# Doubts with timeouts after updating Retrofit

Tags: android, kotlin, retrofit, retrofit2, rx-java2

I was using old versions of Retrofit for making my application available for old devices.

```
//Retrofit
//MUST NOT UPDATE CAUSE RETROFIT just dropped support for Android 4
//noinspection GradleDependency
implementation 'com.squareup.retrofit2:retrofit:2.6.4'
//noinspection GradleDependency
implementation 'com.squareup.retrofit2:converter-gson:2.6.4'
//MUST NOT UPDATE CAUSE OKHTTP just dropped support for Android 4
//noinspection GradleDependency
implementation "com.squareup.okhttp3:logging-interceptor:3.12.2"
implementation 'com.squareup.retrofit2:converter-scalars:2.6.4'
```

My way to handle with timeouts on Rest calls was this:

```
private val okHttpClient =
    OkHttpClient().newBuilder()
        .addInterceptor(loggingInterceptor.apply {
            level = HttpLoggingInterceptor.Level.BASIC
        })
        .addInterceptor {
            try {
                val request =
                    it.request().newBuilder()
                        .addHeader(Constants.SAGAPOLL_VERSION_KEY, sagaPollVersion)
                        .addHeader(Constants.USERNAME_KEY, SharedPref.getString(Constants.USERNAME_KEY))
                        .addHeader(Constants.PASSWORD_KEY, SharedPref.getString(Constants.PASSWORD_KEY))
                        .build()
                it.proceed(request)
            } catch (e: Exception) {
                //Here is where I handle the timeout
                SurveySendingUtils.setSending(false)
                EventBus.getDefault().post(SurveySendingErrorEvent())
                null
            }
        }
        .callTimeout(TIMEOUT, TimeUnit.SECONDS)
        .connectTimeout(TIMEOUT, TimeUnit.SECONDS)
        .readTimeout(TIMEOUT, TimeUnit.SECONDS)
        .writeTimeout(TIMEOUT, TimeUnit.SECONDS)
        .build()
```

I handle the EventBus post in the class that is trying to send the survey, and I display a Dialog to retry the call.

But after upgrading the minimum Android sdk, I've been able to update retrofit dependencies like this:

```
//Retrofit
implementation 'com.squareup.retrofit2:retrofit:2.8.1'
implementation 'com.squareup.retrofit2:converter-gson:2.6.4'
implementation "com.squareup.okhttp3:logging-interceptor:4.7.2"
implementation 'com.squareup.retrofit2:converter-scalars:2.6.4'
```

And now I cannot return null in the addInterceptor lambda, so I do the next:

```
private val okHttpClient =
    OkHttpClient().newBuilder()
        .addInterceptor(loggingInterceptor.apply {
            level = HttpLoggingInterceptor.Level.BASIC
        })
        .addInterceptor {
            try {
                val request =
                    it.request().newBuilder()
                        .addHeader(Constants.SAGAPOLL_VERSION_KEY, sagaPollVersion)
                        .addHeader(
                            Constants.USERNAME_KEY,
                            SharedPref.getString(Constants.USERNAME_KEY)
                        )
                        .addHeader(
                            Constants.PASSWORD_KEY,
                            SharedPref.getString(Constants.PASSWORD_KEY)
                        )
                        .build()
                it.proceed(request)
            } catch (exception: Exception) {
                //Here is where I handle the timeout
                SurveySendingUtils.setSending(false)
                EventBus.getDefault().post(SurveySendingErrorEvent())
                it.proceed(it.request())
            }
        }
        .callTimeout(TIMEOUT, TimeUnit.SECONDS)
        .connectTimeout(TIMEOUT, TimeUnit.SECONDS)
        .readTimeout(TIMEOUT, TimeUnit.SECONDS)
        .writeTimeout(TIMEOUT, TimeUnit.SECONDS)
        .build()
```

So right now, instead of returning null, I'm returning it.proceed(it.request())
Could this make any problem? Is there a cleaner way, without EventBus, to handle the error?

I tried without the try/catch, but I'm not handling anywhere the timeout then (the error never arrives to override fun onError(e: Throwable) {} from the RxJava DisposableObserver)

Thanks,

Mauricio